# How to take a python list index containing multiple strings and split it

Tags: python

I am looking for some help splitting an index from a list containing multiple values and creating a new list with separated values.

```
L = [(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)]
>>>L[0]
(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
```

I need to split that single index into multiple indices in a new list such that:

```
L_Revised = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
>>>L[0]
1
```

So that I can manipulate the individual indices. What code could I use for this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You aren't "splitting" anything in the above example. You have a tuple as the first element of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a generalized case, where you can have more than one tuple in the list, you can flatten your list like this:

```
>>> l = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
>>> [item for tup in l for item in tup]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But if it's a single tuple element list, then probably other answer is easier.

Comment: This is way more than you need.

Comment: Yeah, but for this case only, if there is just one tuple in list. This one is a generalized way to flatten a list of tuple or list of list.

Comment: Thanks Jain, helpful answer, first one was simpler, but this can be used for broader applications, thanks!